# Check if the key exist in scala Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am very new to scala and I have simple `Map[String, String]`.

Example map:

```
val map = Map("a" -> "abc", "b" -> "xyz")
```

I want to write a logic where if a particular key present in the map then call the encrypt() methods on the value and if the key is not present then return empty string.

One way I can do this is:

```
encrypt(map.getOrElse(MARKETPLACE_ID.toString, ""))
```

This will fail incase of key is not present and encrypt() method will be called using empty string.

Please help me to solve this in easiest way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that `map.get` returns an `Option`, you can use its `fold` method.

```
map.get(MARKETPLACE_ID.toString).fold("")(encrypt)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
map.get(MARKETPLACE_ID.toString).map(encrypt).orElse("")
```

You can do it with `Option`, get to `Option` and `map` to `encrypt`, and `orElse` when `Option` is `None`.

Comment: Actually, you should use `getOrElse` rather than `orElse` (`orElse`) takes a fallback `Option[String]` while `getOrElse` takes a fallback `String`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply using `if` statement as

```
if(map.keySet.contains(MARKETPLACE_ID.toString)){
  encrypt(map(MARKETPLACE_ID.toString))
}
```